# Regex to match domain

Tags: regex

Having trouble figuring this out and feeling quite stupid...

I have many urls like this /imagebuilder-ptop.asp?imgCode=166 all I need is a regex that will match /imagebuilder-(ANTHING WHATSOEVER)

If is it /imagebuilder-lkd fa;lsdfh adhf alkdfhdfh   I want to match it...anything.

Answer (score 3):

`/imagebuilder-(.*)` would do it.

Comment: Crazy easy...  thanks a ton, David...  You available for hire?

Comment: No problem.  And, no, unfortunately I'm taken at the moment.